# input textarea nowrap

Tags: html, css, nowrap

nowrap for my textarea isnt working. Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong? Here is my code from .php file:

```
<div class="uprava">
<input id="inputBox" type="textarea" name="obsah" value="<?php echo $obsah; ?>"/>
</div>
<script>document.getElementById("inputBox").style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";</script>
```

and here it is from CSS:

```
#inputBox {
    height: 184px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width:auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    padding: 0 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Better use `<textarea></textarea>`

Comment: there I cant use value...

Comment: Try this out : http://jsfiddle.net/hc4cbd2f/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an id markup to the input and simply add the nowrap property with a simple one-line script like how I did here : http://jsfiddle.net/9v2g93dc/2/

```
.uprava input[type=textarea] {height: 184px; font-size: 16px; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px; -webkit-appearance: none; background: #fff; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0; /* border-radius: 2px; */  padding: 0 8px; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

Comment: and if I need use value there?

Comment: jsfiddle link updated

Comment: It looks good but I dont know why its not working for me

Comment: jsfiddle updated again. If this too doesn't work, then it's most probably the php that is the cause of your issue and not the html

Comment: Can you upvote my answer since I noticed that you've updated the question with my method.

Comment: Question updated but still not working :-/